# Mount docker volume to host machine path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to access test result files in the host from the container. I know that I need to create a volume which maps between host and container, like below, but I get nothing written to the host.

```
docker run --rm -it -v <host_directory_path>:<container_path> imagename
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Program/MyApplication.Program.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Program/MyApplication.Program.csproj
COPY nuget.config ./
WORKDIR ./src/MyApplication.Program/
RUN dotnet restore
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src ./src
WORKDIR ./src/MyApplication.Program/
RUN dotnet build MyApplication.Program.csproj -c Release

FROM builder as tester
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/MyApplication.UnitTests.csproj ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/MyApplication.UnitTests.csproj
WORKDIR ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/
RUN dotnet restore
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./test ./test
WORKDIR ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/
RUN dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "reportgenerator", "-reports:coverage.cobertura.xml", "-targetdir:codecoveragereports", "-reportTypes:htmlInline"]
```

The command at the entry point is working correctly.  It is writing the output to the `MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports` directory, but not to the host directory.

My docker run looks as follows:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /codecoveragereports:/app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports routethink.tests:latest
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try declaring the docker directory as a volume in your dockerfile? `VOLUME /app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports`

Comment: Declaring a `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile mostly only causes unexpected side-effects; it has no effect on the `docker run -v` option.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mounting-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container

"If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount." Your output is being written, but is being obscured when you bind mount the volume at runtime.

Just leaving this here as a diagnosis, not a cure.

Comment: @Siyu I assume / represents the path from which I am running `docker run`?

Comment: @Siyu that was my problem!  Thank you - feel free to create an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue.

`-v /codecoveragereports:/app/***/codecoveragereports` is mounting a directory under the root `/` which is dangerous and you may not have the permission.

It's better to mount locally, like `-v $PWD/codecoveragereports:/app/***/codecoveragereports`, where `$PWD` is an environment variable equal to the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks - this works - my problem was that I assumed it was defaulting to the execution directory, without $PWD.